# Left out tata's

Tags: fallout-4

I have a number of settlers assigned for farming in my rather oversized farm however there always seems to be plenty of spare fruit/veg left when I visit.

I check in the storage and there's sometimes like 30-40 harvested, but most of the time it's more like 6-10 with plenty left on the floors.

Do I need more harvesters? Are they bugged?

Comment: What? What do you mean left on the floor? What do you mean 30-40 harvested? What's bugged?

Comment: Am I the only one who read the title, and saw the down-votes, and initially thought this question would be complaining about a lack of nudity in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to doublecheck is efficient assignment. If you assigned all of your settlers to plants side by side in a large field of plants, you will have wasted overlapping. Each settler will use up to 6 nearby plants for harvesting, but if you assign them all to 1 side of a massive field, you will see only about half the plants are actually assigned. To check this, go into build mode, and mouse over a settler. The plants assigned will be highlighted. By building a bell near the farm, you can summon all the villagers to more easily check just how much of the farm is actually assigned.